# g:paginate unknown tag in Grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails, groovy, pagination, ggts

I use Grails 2.4.4, Java8 and want to use the [paginate tag](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.4/ref/Tags/paginate.html) like this:

```
<g:paginate total="${totalCount ?: 0}" />
```

My GGTS 3.6.3 underlines the tag and shows me that this is an unkown tag. In an older GGTS version with Grails 2.3.11 the tag works fine.

**How do I get the paginate tag to work in grails 2.4.x?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work when you run the app? If so, I would just ignore the GGTS error. This IDE often generates bogus errors when developing Grails apps.

Comment: No it does not run on run.

Comment: There is only a hint when you go with the mouse over the tag that says "Unknown tag (g:paginate)." The tag itself is underlined yellow.

Comment: Well you where right it worked but it shows still the hint that the tag is missing. I filed an issue at grails issue tracker.

Comment: @confile you should file that under the GGTS issue tracker, rather than the Grails issue tracker